# What does Elasticsearch's auto_generate_phrase_queries do?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the docs for query string query, `auto_generate_phrase_queries` is listed as a parameter but the only description is "defaults to false." So what does this parameter do exactly?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will directly match to the lucene's `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserSettings#autoGeneratePhraseQueries`. When the analyzer applied on the query string, this setting allows lucene to generate quoted phrases no keywords.

[Quoting](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201202.mbox/%3CC0551C512C863540BC59694A118452AA0764A434@ITS-EMBX-03.adsroot.itcs.umich.edu%3E):

> SOLR-2015: Add a boolean attribute autoGeneratePhraseQueries to TextField.
>     autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" (the default) causes the query parser to
>     generate phrase queries if multiple tokens are generated from a single
>     non-quoted analysis string.  For example WordDelimiterFilter splitting text:pdp-11
>     will cause the parser to generate text:"pdp 11" rather than (text:PDP OR text:11).
>     Note that autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" tends to not work well for non whitespace
>     delimited languages.

where word delimiter works as [WordDelimiterFilter.html](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html)

Important thing to note is `single non-quoted analysis string`, i.e. if your query string is non-quoted. If you are already searching for a quoted phrase then it won't make any sense.